# jquery check if a checkbox from a class is checked and load php file?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check whether a checkbox from either my class 'group1' or my class 'group2' is checked or not.

I am trying to use jquery to check If a checkbox from 'group1' is checked then load my php file 'maintenance.php'

else if a checkbox from 'group2' is checked then load my php file 'travel.php'

The problem I have is if a user checks a checkbox from group1 then the php file loads as it should but when/if the user unchecks it after the page is still shown, but instead as soon as the checkbox is unchecked I want the php file not to show.

Can someone please show me where I am going wrong here? Thanks

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group1" value="same">Option 
        <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group1" value="same">Option
        <br> 
        <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group2" value="same">Option
        <input type="checkbox" name="option" id="option" class="group2" value="same">Option
```

jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=option]').change(function () {
        if($(this).hasClass('group1')) {
            $('#placeholder').load("dependables/maintenance.php");
        } else if($(this).hasClass('group2')) {
            $('#placeholder').load("dependables/travel.php");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're only checking if `this` has the class that you've specified. You're not checking, if it is the one which has been selected.

So, use `$.fn.is` like below with psedu-selector `:checked`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=option]').change(function () {
        if($(this).is('.group1:checked')) {
            $('#placeholder').load("dependables/maintenance.php");
        } else if($(this).is('.group2:checked')) {
            $('#placeholder').load("dependables/travel.php");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for this but I tried the code and it doesn't seem to work, it works when a user checks a checkbox and shows the php file, but when they uncheck the checkbox the php file is still showing? any ideas?